# Reset Font Size in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to change the font size of text in canvas. I have tried below option but it isn't working properly. Lets say i have enlarge the text by using control option and after that if i am applying font size then it doesn't working.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
var add_text = new fabric.IText('Hello World', { 
 left: 50, 
 top: 50,
 fontSize:20,
});

canvas.add(add_text);
canvas.renderAll();

$('.manage_font_size').change(function(){
 var cur_value = $(this).val();
 if(cur_value!='')
 {
  var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  //Check that text is selected
  if(activeObj==undefined)
  {
   alert('Please select a Text');
   return false;
  }
  activeObj.set({
   fontSize: cur_value
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
 }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<select class="manage_font_size">
 <option>select</option>
 <option value="10">10 PX</option>
 <option value="20">20 PX</option>
 <option value="30">30 PX</option>
 <option value="40">40 PX</option>
</select>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: You can check by doing this: first select the text and make it big then change the font size. I am trying to set font size but its look like it was adding or subtracting font size from object's current font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the `scaleX` and `scaleY` back to 1 to negate the size change and then apply `fontSize`

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
var add_text = new fabric.IText('Hello World', { 
 left: 50, 
 top: 50,
 fontSize:20,
});

canvas.add(add_text);
canvas.renderAll();

$('.manage_font_size').change(function(){
 var cur_value = $(this).val();
 if(cur_value!='')
 {
  var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  //Check that text is selected
  if(activeObj==undefined)
  {
   alert('Please select a Text');
   return false;
  }
  activeObj.set({
      scaleX:1,
      scaleY:1,
   fontSize: cur_value
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
 }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<select class="manage_font_size">
 <option>select</option>
 <option value="10">10 PX</option>
 <option value="20">20 PX</option>
 <option value="30">30 PX</option>
 <option value="40">40 PX</option>
</select>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```